# Gosublime:How does it can show me the function's params informations when it works

Tags: go, gosublime

It can work good with sublime text 2,now i want to know the function's params count and type,it only show me the function's return type. The plugin can't do the thing,is there any methods can solve the problem ? or we can modify the code to reach it

Comment: the code is at https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime and uses https://github.com/nsf/gocode internally.

Comment: The status bar in the bottom left hand corner has the function signature when your cursor is on it/about to type it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I *think* he's asking how gosublime does it, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start typing, the auto-completion will indeed show you only the return type.

But as soon as you select one (and remember, with Go, you will have only one method with a given name), you will see the function parameters directly in the code.

To get more out of the tooltip presented by GoSublime, you would have to modify the [`gosubl/mg9.py`](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/blob/master/gosubl/mg9.py) script.

Comment: thank you ,you mean that I must open the package code to see the param's type,right? I just want to know the param's type,because when i'm coding,I can not remember all functions or methods params type,so if the gosublime can do it?

Comment: @zhengkang As soon as you select a function, you see its parameters, but not their type. However, if you click on the function you just selected (and which is now on your editor), you will see the types in the lower left corner, in the status bar at the bottom of Sublime Text.

Comment: Oh,Yes,I was so careless that ignore it. Thank you very much.^_^